# R Markdown broken image icon in Xaringan presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

I am new to `Xaringan` presentations in `R` and right now I am trying to create a demo `presentation`. Currently, I am facing an issue with displaying a `picture` from a local network drive path (same path for both the .md and .png file).

The image outputs fine in the `chunk output` but appears as a `broken icon` after `knitting`.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this?

Code

```
# Introduce yourself

> Hello, my name is Ed.

---
class: center, middle

# Slide with centered content in the middle

My name is Ed and I like to eat gravy and hangout with Edd and Eddy.

---
class: inverse, center, middle

# Slide with Ed's picture

![img_caption](O:/network_drive_path/ed.png)
```

Comment: Even after copying the `image` file to the `Presentation_files` folder, I am still having the same problem.

Comment: Never mind, the image opens fine if you open the file in the browser.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use relative paths. `O:/network_drive_path/ed.png` is an absolute path.